# How to create a mongo table using a JSON

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm doing a game, and when I create a player, I want to take some values from the database and add it to the user table.

So I want a table with some values, like:

```
var initSchema = new Schema({
    buildings: { type: Array, required: true, default: []},
    researches: { type: Array, required: true, default: []}
});
```

So when I create a player I can just pick `buildings`and `researches`and add it to the player model.

The point of this schema is that only needs to be created one time. Then I only need to read the values. It's like the 'default' values when I create a player.

I think a possible solution is to create a kind of JSON file with the values, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said it is going to be default values for a player, I don't think Schema is the correct solution here. JSON file will do. Since it is a node.js app, what you can do is write all the necessary information into a JSON file, like

```
{
    buildings: ['Pentagon', 'White House'],
    researches: ['Bioengineering', 'Drawing Lines']
}
```

and read the file using the fs module of nodejs. For example:

```
fs.readFile('./buildings.json', function (err, data) {
   console.log(data);
});
```

More detail are covered in the API
http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readsync_fd_buffer_offset_length_position

Answer (score 0):

I think, this can help you.

https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native

There are some example about it.